# Trying to understand which is better in python creating variables or using expressions

Tags: python, coding-style, comparison

One of the practices I have gotten into in Python from the beginning is to reduce the number of variables I create as compared to the number I would create when trying to do the same thing in SAS or Fortran

for example here is some code I wrote tonight:

```
def idMissingFilings(dEFilings,indexFilings):
    inBoth=set(indexFilings.keys()).intersection(dEFilings.keys())
    missingFromDE=[]
    for each in inBoth:
        if len(dEFilings[each])<len(indexFilings[each]):

            dEtemp=[]
            for filing in dEFilings[each]:
                #dateText=filing.split("\\")[-1].split('-')[0]
                #year=dateText[0:5]
                #month=dateText[5:7]
                #day=dateText[7:]
                #dETemp.append(year+"-"+month+"-"+day+"-"+filing[-2:])    
            dEtemp.append(filing.split('\\')[-1].split('-')[0][1:5]+"-"+filing.split('\\')[-1].split('-')[0][5:7]+"-"+filing.split('\\')[-1].split('-')[0][7:]+"-"+filing[-2:])
            indexTemp=[]
            for infiling in indexFilings[each]:
                indexTemp.append(infiling.split('|')[3]+"-"+infiling[-6:-4])
            tempMissing=set(indexTemp).difference(dEtemp)
            for infiling in indexFilings[each]:
                if infiling.split('|')[3]+"-"+infiling[-6:-4] in tempMissing:
                    missingFromDE.append(infiling)
    return missingFromDE
```

Now I split one of the strings I am processing 4 times in the line dEtemp.append(blah blah blah)

```
filing.split('\\')
```

Historically in Fortran or SAS if I were to attempt the same I would have 'sliced' my string once and assigned a variable to each part of the string that I was going to use in this expression.

I am constantly forcing myself to use expressions instead of first resolving to a value and using the value.  The only reason I do this is that I am learning by mimicking other people's code but it has been in the back of my mind to ask this question - where can I find a cogent discussion of why one is better than the other

The code compares a set of documents on a drive and a source list of those documents and checks to see whether all of those from the source are represented on the drive

Okay the commented section is much easier to read and how I decided to respond to nosklos answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, it is not better to put everything in the expression. Please use variables.

Using variables is not only better because you will do the operation only once and save the value for multiple uses. The main reason is that code becomes more readable that way. If you name the variable right, it doubles as free implicit documentation!

Comment: Gosh so you are suggesting I am learning and forcing on myself bad habits.

Comment: I concur with nosklo.  I have never read anywhere that minimizing the number of variables was good practice, in Python or anything else. All those scattered split() calls are giving me a, well, a headache. Your commented code is so much clearer to follow than that 1-line monster, plus you only evaluate that ugly `filing.split(...` expression once instead of multiple times, which is costing you a considerable performance penalty as well.  Also, learn some other Python idioms, like list unpacking: `year,month,day = datetext.split('/')`  (I'm assuming that your date fields are '/' delimited).

Comment: Isn't there something in the rule book about eliminating redudantly-duplicated code too ?

Comment: I would stop well short of “Please use variables.”; they can be overused just like anything else, forcing the reader to keep large amounts of name mapping state in mind to interpret the ultimate use, and to watch out for more uses/assignments.

Comment: @DavisHerring "please use variables" as opposed to go out of your way to not use variables at all, which is what the OP was doing. The answer doesn't ask you to use **only** variables.

Comment: @nosklo: Fair enough: the nuanced answer is somewhere in the middle, as usual.  I’ve seen too many people follow the three words, unqualified, for me to say nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use more variables. Python is known for its readability; taking away that feature is called not "Pythonic" (See https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/). Code that is more readable will be easier for others to understand, and easier to understand yourself later.