# I'm looking for a more succinct way to get len of multiple function parameters

Tags: python, function, parameters

I'm looking for a more succinct way to get len of multiple function parameters

I've tried doing Google searches to count parameters defined in a function and not finding clear answers. They may be clear to more experienced programmers, but I am very new - like 5 days in.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I get the result I want with this, but looking for maybe a shorter method?

```
def get_length(first_name, middle_name, last_name):
    countme1 = len(first_name)
    countme2 = len(middle_name)
    countme3 = len(last_name)
    print(countme1 + countme2 + countme3)

get_length("David", "Daniel", "Wesisenheimer")
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: What you want to do? Can you please give more info?

Comment: Sorry - yes.  The objective is to print the len of all three parameters added together.  The above program works as intended, but I'm thinking I could get the same results with a more succinct method.

Comment: `print(len(first_name + middle_name + last_name))`. BTW, there are _three_ parameters to this function, so count parameters in the subject line is misleading.

Comment: Thank you!  I will re-title the post.  I'm very new so I will probably make more mistakes here.

Comment: *Why* does it matter that this short function be even shorter?  (Do the parameters need names and to always be three in number?)

Comment: @DavisHerring I just wanted to know how to perform the intended function without having to assign multiple variables, less typing - same results.

Comment: @yes_I_am_new: So… just lose the assignments and use the expression assigned rather than the variable name the one time each appears?

Comment: @DavisHerring Yep, got it to work.  I know this was a reach for help with a very basic inquiry, so appreciate your patience!

Comment: Does this (asked in reverse) answer your question? [Trying to understand which is better in python creating variables or using expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516118/trying-to-understand-which-is-better-in-python-creating-variables-or-using-expre)

Comment: @DavisHerring Reading that, I did take from it that using variables in your code makes it easier for you and/or others to review and understand what's happening under the hood.  I get that and want to get into good practices as I learn Python, but I also want to see and understand how more experienced coders accomplish more with less.  Thank you for following up!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to sum the length of multiple strings (the number of which is unknown) is with iteration. Also, the asterisk (*) means 'all' in python. So *args means that the function will accept many or few parameters, zero parameters being the least value.

```
def get_length(*args):
    if len(args) == 1: # If only one parameter (hence, one string) was given
        return len(args[0])
    else:
        sum_lens = 0
        for string in args:
            sum_lens = sum_lens + len(string)
        return sum_lens
```

## Or the faster (and more succinct) method

```
# (from user:4518341)
def get_length(*args):    
    return sum(len(arg) for arg in args)
```

Comment: Simpler: `return sum(len(arg) for arg in args)`. Also the star indicates zero or more, not one or more.